# What is maximum length of MIDL helpstring attrubute?

Tags: com, typelib, midl

Looks like MIDL helpstring attribute has a limitation on string length although not [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/helpstring).
As I see, it's around 260 characters (similar to `MAX_PATH` constant).
Does anybody know something about it?

Comment: It's not documented per se but if you compile using midl with warning enabled (midl.exe blah.idl /W2) you should see the "warning MIDL2534 : string constant exceeds limit of 255 characters" message. I think error is wrong, it should be 260 (it's indeed truncated at 260...)

Comment: In fact the 255 max is documented for string *constants*: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/const so it looks like the compiler uses the same algorithm for documentation strings...